# Expected number of occurrences of events with probability dependent on previous events (for example lottery jackpots)

Tags: probability, distributions, conditional-probability

The real life example of my problem would be a lottery jackpot. Let's say it starts at £2m and is won with 10% probability. If nobody wins then it is £4m with 15% probability that somebody wins. And so on and so forth (£6m/20%, etc.) until somebody wins. Then everything resets back to £2m and 10% and starts again.

How can I calculate how many instances of £2m, £4m, £6m etc. are expected in the next `X` instances if today the jackpot is `Y`?

For example,  if today the jackpot is £2m in the next 10 rounds the expected value is `a` times of £2m, `b` times of £4m, `c` times of £6m, etc...

Also it would be great to get an idea of what is the distribution of those `a`, `b`, `c` ... numbers.

I imagine it won't be a normal distribution but I really don't know how to think about it.

Comment: The jackpot of £2 looks like a typo, but I edited only for grammar and style, not content.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Short answer: A variant to the [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution).

**Simpler case: When the probability for the occurance of the event is independent of the jackpot**

The geometric distribution relates to the case that the probability of the jackpot is constant, e.g. this 10% remains the same for each draw.

- The probability that the jackpot is won in the first draw is 10%.
- The probability that the jackpot is won in the second draw is the probability to miss it in the first case (90% probability) and then get it in the second case (10% probability). Which is computed as $0.9 \times 0.1$.
- The probability that the jackpot is won in the thirdnd draw is the probability to miss it in the first *and* second case (two times 90% probability) and then get it in the third case (10% probability). Which is computed as $0.9 \times 0.9 \times 0.1$.
- etcetera

When $p$ is the (constant) probability that the jackpot is won in any draw, then the general formula is:

$$\text{P(win in the $k$-th draw)} = 
\overset{{\substack{\llap{\text{probability to win the $k$-th}}\rlap{\text{ draw, if we get there}} }}}{\overbrace{p}^{}}
 \times \underset{{\substack{\llap{\text{probability to get}}\rlap{\text{ to the $k$-th draw}} \\ \llap{\text{ie. probability of no }} \rlap{\text{win in the first k-1 draws}}}}}{\underbrace{(1-p)^{k-1}}_{}}$$

**When the probability for the occurrence of the event is not independent**

For a non constant probability that the jackpot is won, say $p_k = 0.05 + 0.05 k$, you get a formula with a product term over all those $p_k$:

$$\text{P(win in the $k$-th draw)} = p_k \prod_{i=1}^{k-1} (1-p_k) $$

If we write this product term explicitly:

$$ \begin{array}{}
\text{P(k=1)} &=& p_1 &=& 0.1 \\
\text{P(k=2)} &=& p_2 \times (1-p_1) &=& 0.15 \times 0.9 \\
\text{P(k=3)} &=& p_3 \times (1-p_2) \times (1-p_1) &=& 0.2 \times 0.85 \times 0.9 \\
\text{P(k=4)} &=& p_4 \times (1-p_3) \times (1-p_2) \times (1-p_1) &=& 0.25 \times 0.8 \times 0.85 \times 0.9 \\
\text{P(k=n)} &=& p_n \prod_{i=1}^{n-1} (1-p_i)
\end{array}$$

A graph of a computation for your specific example is plotted below:

[image: example]

R-code to replicate this:

```r
r = 20
b = 2/r
a = 1/r
n <- r-b*r

pk <- b+a*c(0:n)
qk <- c(1,head(cumprod((1-pk)),-1))
plot(1:(n+1),pk * qk, ylim = c(0,0.17),
     xlab = "draw number k",
     ylab = "prbability")
text(1:12+c(rep(0,2),-0.5,0.5,rep(0,8)),(pk * qk)[1:12],paste0(round(10000*pk * qk)[1:12]/100, " %"), pos=3, cex = 0.5)
sum(pk*qk)
```

---

#### Expectation value

For the expectation you sum over all those probabilities multiplied with $k$. $$E(K) = \sum k P(K=k)$$

An elegant way to compute the expectation value would be to use the cumulative distribution function and integrate over it.

We have $$P(K\leq k) = 1- \prod_{1\leq i \leq k} (1-p_i)$$

and for a range $1 \leq k \leq n$

$$E(K) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} 1-P(K\leq k) =  \sum_{k=1}^{n} \prod_{1\leq i \leq k} (1-p_i) $$

---

#### Long answer: A scaled and shifted [$\chi$ distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi_distribution).

If your real-life example has a very large range and the summation is not easy to perform, then we can use an approximation. For instance, say we have $p_k = b + a\cdot (k-1)$ with $\frac{a}{1-b}$ very small (other scenarios for $p_k$ are possible as well and this method can be generalized*).

With some handwaving we could say that

$$ \frac{\partial P(K > k)}{\partial k}  \approx - P(K > k)  p_i $$

or

$$ \frac{\partial \log(P(K > k)) }{\partial k}   \approx  -p_i $$

and integrating this, then taking the exponent, and inverting the equality gives:

$$P(K \leq k) = 1 - e^{-0.5 a k^2 -  b k + c}$$

where $c$ is an integration constant that can be set to make $P(K \leq 1) = b$. We can relate this to a $\chi$ distribution with 2 degrees of freedom

$$P(X \leq x) = 1 - e^{-x^2/2}$$

It would be possible to make the conversion to that $\chi$ distributed variable by scaling and shifting but it is easier to compute $P(X \leq x)$ and take the difference or derivative.

This is done with the code below and it provides the the blue and green lines in the above figure:

```r
k <- c(1:(n+1))
Fk <- 1-exp(-0.5*a*k^2-b*k+0.5*a+b)*(1-b)
ks <- seq(1,n+1,0.1)-0.5
dk <- exp(-0.5*a*ks^2-b*ks+0.5*a+b)*(1-b)*(b+a*ks) 
lines(k,diff(c(0,Fk)),col=4)
lines(ks+0.5,dk,col=3)
```

---

** A generalization could be made roughly with something like $P(K = k) \approx p_k e^{-\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} p_k}$ where we define $p_0 = 0$. Note that this is a bit analogous to the $f(t) = s(t)e^{\int_0^t-s(t) dt}$ expression in https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/354574/164061*